# How to do a recursive function in mips?

Tags: mips, recurrence

As a homework i have to code this recursive function into MIPS(should compute the N-th element of this recurrence relation). But I'm not sure how can I do the recursive step twice:

[image: code]

Anyone can help me with a piece of code?
Please :)

Comment: A recursive call it just a call to the same function that you're already in. There isn't really anything special about it. If you need to preserve some value that could be changed by subsequent calls, place it on the stack.

Comment: Ok...but what about Hi and Lo registers for the multiply of 10.5 and f(N-2)....oh and also there is a signed number...-10.5 ?    :(